# java nullPointerException when converting a string[] to int[]

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

Below i have an extract from a school project i am trying to debug it but i am losing my head on this one, i am using the auto generated text document to but on line 47 when i try to break the 3rd line of the .txt down into a stock count integer i keep on getting a nullPointerException error, i have tried t put it into an if statement but i still seems to not want get rid of the nullPointerException, if anyone could help i would be highly grateful.
regards,

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    if(fis1.isFile() == true) {
        try{
            InputStream = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(
                "I:/WORKSPACE/Vending Machine/src/Vendor/SETTINGS.txt"));
            String l1;
            String l2;
            String l3;
            l1 = InputStream.readLine();
            l2 = InputStream.readLine();
            l3 = InputStream.readLine();

            stocks = l1.split("-");
            String[] stockprcstr =  l2.split("-");

            for(int i = 0; i < stockprcstr.length; i++) {
                if(stockprcstr[i] == null) {
                    stockprc[i] = 0.0;
                } else {
                    stockprc[i] = Double.parseDouble(stockprcstr[i]);
                }
            }

            String[] stockstr = l3.split("-");
            for(int i = 0; i < stockstr.length;i++) {
                if(stockstr[i] == null){
                    stock[i] = 0;
                } else {
                    System.out.println("int stock: " +  String.valueOf(stock[i]));
                    System.out.println("str stock: " + stockstr[i]);

                    stock[i] = Integer.parseInt(stockstr[i]);
                }
            }
        } finally {
            if(InputStream != null){
                InputStream.close();
            }
        }
    } else {
        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("I:/WORKSPACE/Vending Machine/src/Vendor/SETTINGS.txt");
        writer.println("pipsi-note Cola-Tactical Bacon-Crunchin Crisps-");
        writer.println("2.50-3.00-4.00-3.50-");
        writer.println("5-5-5-5-");
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You can replace with `if(fis1.isFile() == true)` with `if (fis1.isFile())`. The `== true` is not necessary.

Comment: stock[i] = Integer.parseInt(stockstr[i]);

Comment: Did you initialize `stock`? I don't see an `int[]` declaration anywhere in this code

Comment: yeah it get initialized up the top but i didnt specify an array length though

Comment: @Piemansam5 Then that's not initialization. That's declaration.

Comment: @Piemansam5 variable declaration **IS NOT** variable initialization...

Comment: Yeah, you're not initializing the `stock` array. You're declaring it. If you wanted to initialize it you'd need to assign a new array object to the variable, like `int[] stock = new int[size]`

Comment: thanks a lot forthat haha life savers

Comment: one of `readLine()` returns null